# Python - load transaction data into a list of lists, count occurrence of each string

Tags: python

I'm getting back into python on account of having a homework assignment in it, and am looking for assistance on speeding up sections of my code. My last post was downvoted on account of not providing my ideas, so this time I will do better.

I have a text file of purchasing transactions that looks like this:

```
A B C D E F
A E F G H I J K 
A B D E F G H
B C D F G H
G H I K J
G H I J
B C D H J K
B C D H K
A C E G I K
A B D F G H I
A B C D E F G H I J K
A B C D E
C D F G
C E F G H I
C D E J K
J K
G H I J K
A B D
A C D K
A B D I J K
A B C E F G 
F G I J K
A F G K 
B C E F G H
A D E
A B 
C D E F 
C E F G H I J
I J K
E F H I J K
```

where each letter corresponds to a purchase of a specific product, and each row is a transaction (for the first row, somebody bought products A B C D E and F). I need to do a preliminary count of how many times each product has been bought, and then create a list of items that were purchased at least S times. This is what my code looks like:

```
import itertools
import operator

item_data_lol = []
with open("test_file.txt") as inputfile:
   for line in inputfile:
       item_data_lol.append(line.strip().split(','))

# this is what item_data_lol loads in as
# [['A B C D E F'], ['A E F G H I J K'], ['A B D E F G H'], ['B C D F G H'], ['G H I K J'], ['G H I J'], ['B C D H J K'], ['B C D H K'], ['A C E G I K'], ['A B D F G H I'], ['A B C D E F G H I J K'], ['A B C D E'], ['C D F G'], ['C E F G H I'], ['C D E J K'], ['J K'], ['G H I J K'], ['A B D'], ['A C D K'], ['A B D I J K'], ['A B C E F G'], ['F G I J K'], ['A F G K'], ['B C E F G H'], ['A D E'], ['A B'], ['C D E F'], ['C E F G H I J'], ['I J K'], ['E F H I J K']]

S = 14

# initialize dictionary to count frequency of individual items
first_lookup = {}

# loop over each row, then each element, obtaining a total element count for each element 
for line in item_data_lol:
    line = line[0]
    for item in line.split():
        if item in first_lookup.keys():
            first_lookup[item] += 1
        else:
            first_lookup[item] = 1


# Get list of frequent items
frequent_items = []
for this_key, this_value in first_lookup.iteritems():
    if this_value > support_threshold:
        frequent_items.append(this_key)

print(first_lookup)
print(frequent_items)
```

This structuring of the code works fine for my small dataset, however when I run my program on the full txt file provided, this takes surprisingly long. This code is only a small part of a larger algorithm I have to write (apriori algorithm for finding frequent itemsets), and therefore it is concerning that this first part is taking as long as it does. If i can speed this part of the code up using different python functions (i mostly use for loops and if cases since I am rusty with python and do not remember many of the functions), then I can probably speed up later parts of my program as well.

Appreciate any thoughts on how to speed this up

Comment: using a `Counter` or `defaultdict` from `collections` might speed things up rather than using your hooks.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: yes, natural way to go. But the problem was even worse than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You encountered the sadly classical test on dictionary keys instead of in the dictionary itself.

```
if item in first_lookup.keys():
```

should be

```
if item in first_lookup:
```

to benefit from dictionary lookup. Explicit call to `first_lookup.keys()` generates a `list` in Python 2, so `in` applies to a list not a dictionary.

In your case, replacing that loop:

```
for line in item_data_lol:
    line = line[0]
    for item in line.split():
        if item in first_lookup.keys():
            first_lookup[item] += 1
        else:
            first_lookup[item] = 1
```

by this would speed it up even more (using `collections.Counter` initialized by a generator comprehension):

```
import collections
first_lookup = collections.Counter(item for line in item_data_lol for item in line[0].split())
```

Comment: thanks for insight, although i received an error trying to run your collections.Counter() function - 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: sorry, fixed, missed () after split!!

Comment: i will definitely remove the .keys() form the if statement. what magnitude does this slow code down by? just a bit or a large factor?

Comment: @Canovice if you are on Python 2, it will slow it down *tremendously*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga in python 3 it's not good either. `keys()` isn't a list, but isn't a `set()` either.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre AFAIK in Python 3, `dict_keys` is a view which still maintains the O(1) membership testing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you may be right. I'll run some benches to convince myself.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre indeed, `dict_keys` supports set operations, like union `|` and intersection `&`

Comment: c is a collections.Counter object. I tested the 3 lines of code that adds elements to frequent_items, and the code still works. Can i always operate on this collections.Counter type object in a similar manner as if it was a dictionary?

Comment: It is a subclass of `dict`. Checkout `isinstance(collections.Counter(), dict)`. Most of the time, it is interchangable.