# Python - creating pairs of tuples from

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the second post relating to a homework assignment of mine trying to code the apriori algorithm in python - see [Python - load transaction data into a list of lists, count occurrence of each string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814627/python-load-transaction-data-into-a-list-of-lists-count-occurrence-of-each-st/41814714#41814714). I received help loading in my data faster and counting the number of times each item appeared in my dataset. This next section of my code runs quite slowly, and I am not very familiar with the best-use of python functions to speed these operations up, so as you will see i lean heavily on for loops and if cases. Here is my code, with a list and a dictionary that were created earlier in the code simply replicated for use:

```
# a dict and a list that are built earlier
item_data_lol = [['A B C D E F'], ['A E F G H I J K'], ['A B D E F G H'], ['B C D F G H'], ['G H I K J'], ['G H I J'], ['B C D H J K'], ['B C D H K'], ['A C E G I K'], ['A B D F G H I'], ['A B C D E F G H I J K'], ['A B C D E'], ['C D F G'], ['C E F G H I'], ['C D E J K'], ['J K'], ['G H I J K'], ['A B D'], ['A C D K'], ['A B D I J K'], ['A B C E F G'], ['F G I J K'], ['A F G K'], ['B C E F G H'], ['A D E'], ['A B'], ['C D E F'], ['C E F G H I J'], ['I J K'], ['E F H I J K']]

first_lookup = collections.Counter(item for line in item_data_lol for item in line[0].split())
frequent_items = ['A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'G', 'F', 'I', 'H', 'K', 'J']
```

essentially, item_data_lol is a list of transactions, where the letters indicate a specific product being bought. I am trying to find pairs of products that are often bought together, and I am only considering pairs of products that fall within the frequent_items list. For example, the first transaction was A B C D E F, indicating these 6 products were all bought together. Here's what I have so far.

```
# initialize second dict to count frequency of pairs of items
second_lookup = {}

# loop over each pair in frequent_tuples, creating a key/value pair in the dict for them
n = len(frequent_items)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):   
        item_1 = frequent_items[i]
        item_2 = frequent_items[j]
        if item_1 < item_2:
            this_key = (item_1, item_2)
            second_lookup[this_key] = 0

# loop through each row of the data again, create all possible combinations of pairs
# check if each pair is a key in second_lookup, if so increment the value by 1 
for line in item_data_lol:
    line = line[0]

    # nested for loop over the row, needed to create tuple pairs for all items
    for item_1 in line.split():
        for item_2 in line.split():

            # check that the items aren't the same, then created a sorted tuple
            if item_1 < item_2:
                test_key = (item_1, item_2)
                if test_key in second_lookup.keys():
                    second_lookup[test_key] += 1

# filter second_lookup down to only those tuples/pairs with > support_threshold count
frequent_pairs = []
for this_key, this_value in second_lookup.iteritems():
    if this_value > support_threshold:
        frequent_pairs.append(this_key)
```

My strategy is simple, but slow. I first initialize a second_lookup dictionary, and create keys in the dictionary corresponding to every possible pair of 2 products that exists in the frequent_items list. Then I loop over my data (item_data_lol), and for each row/transaction, I create every combination of two items (for the first row, this would be (A,B), (A,C), (A,D), (A,E), (A,F), (B,C), (B,D), (B,E), (B,F), (C,D)...). Then i check whether or not each of these pairs is a key in the second_lookup dictionary, and if it is increment that key's value by 1.

ultimately, this process is very slow. it works at a decent speed on my test data, but not on the larger dataset. Any thoughts are appreciated!

EDIT - i've underestimated the amount of speed improvement from removing .keys() in my if cases. when calling dict.keys(). It alone appears to have fixed the issue.

Comment: If your code is in working order as intended, try asking for improvements here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com Stack Overflow is suited for broken code in hopes of fixing it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: sounds like you didn't learn from your previous Q&A: `if test_key in second_lookup.keys():`. Drop the `keys()` !!!

Comment: I did, and I will make the change to keys() for sure. It's more a general overview of the code that needs improvement.

Comment: although I will remove that and see if it alone improves the performance to the extent that it will run fast enough for its purpose

Comment: didn't know about codereview, can post there for sure, although this code is essentially broken to the extent that it isn't nearly fast enough to perform what it needs to perform.

Comment: Speed of code does not equal broken code, it maybe sub optimal but it's not broken.

Comment: got it. like i said didn't know about codereview, will post similar questions there next time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that does something similar

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools as it

c = Counter(it.chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: it.combinations(x, 2), map(str.split, it.chain.from_iterable(item_data_lol)))))
```

That's ugly though, so to break it down:

```
words = it.chain.from_iterable(item_data_lol)
products_lists = map(str.split, words)
combinations = map(lambda x: it.combinations(x,2) products_list)
c = Counter(it.chain.from_iterable(combinations))
```